# How to centre markers on the svg map paths

Tags: jquery, d3.js, svg

I have a map with states. It is an svg map with paths(states) and I need to add markers to the centre of each path(state).

```
// function to add markers to svg map
function addMarker (svgContainer, lga) {
  const key = '[id=' + '\'' + lga + '\'' + ']';
  const d = d3.select('#map').select('svg')
    .select('g').select('g').select(key).node();
  //calculating the path centre point
  const x = d.getBBox().x + d.getBBox().width/2;
  const y = d.getBBox().y + d.getBBox().height/2;
  // adding marker 
  svgContainer.append('path')
    .attr('d', 'M0,0l-8.8-17.7C-12.1-24.3-7.4-32,0-32h0c7.4,0,12.1,7.7,8.8,14.3L0,0z')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('fill', 'green')
    .attr('stroke-width', 0.005)
    .attr('transform', 'translate('+ x + ','+ y+ ') scale(0.002)');

}
```

[svg map with states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJcZb.png)

Comment: you need to get the bounding box of the state path: `state.getBBox()`. Next you calculate the center of the state's bounding box. you put the "marker" in a symbol and you `<use>` it in the center of the state

Comment: @enxaneta Can you kindly share an example I still find it hard for me to implement using the same

Answer (score 0):

This is an example where I'm using the outline of Catalunya. The bounding box of a path is the smallest rectangle in which the object fits. As you may see the shape of the path I'm using falls mostly in the upper left part of it's bounding box. The "marker" is center in the path's bounding box, not in the centered of the path.

Also I've added a small red circle to the symbol that represents the point {0,0}. You may delete it.

```js
// the bounding box of the path
let bb = catalunya.getBBox()
//the center of the bounding box
let center = {}
center.x = bb.x + bb.width/2;
center.y = bb.y + bb.height/2;
//set the x and y attributes of the use element
theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"x",center.x);
theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"y",center.y);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:90vh}

path{stroke:black;fill:none}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 498 495">
  
  <defs>
   <symbol id="marker" viewBox="-11 -32 22 36" >
    <path id="kk" d='m0, 1 l-8.8, -17.7 c-3.3, -6.6 1.4, -14.3 8.8, -14.3 l0, 0 c7.4, 0 12.1, 7.7 8.8, 14.3 l-8.8, 17.7 z' />
     <circle r="3" fill="red" />
   </symbol>
  </defs>
  
  <use id="theUse" xlink:href="#marker" width="50" height="50"  />
<path id="catalunya" d="M180.778,34.489
 c-7.137,2.339-13.98,3.992-20.299,6.82c-6.115,2.737-9.794,0.969-14.098-3.587c-9.822-10.398-18.969-21.751-35.429-22.507
 c-8.477-0.389-16.839-3.288-25.424-5.09c-5.087,11.759-10.027,23.015-14.773,34.353c-0.587,1.402-0.354,3.267-0.14,4.869
 c5.235,39.11,10.561,78.208,15.692,117.332c0.315,2.406-0.208,5.367-1.406,7.46c-16.886,29.46-33.96,58.812-50.972,88.199
 c-0.586,1.012-1.009,2.118-1.826,3.857c11.056-3.285,21.275-6.321,32.502-9.657c-1.271,2.462-1.909,3.797-2.631,5.084
 c-9.536,16.979-18.984,34.008-28.708,50.878c-2.091,3.629-2.613,6.178,0.625,9.497c3.694,3.788,6.673,8.272,10.009,12.512
 c-0.44,0.856-0.775,1.608-1.195,2.31c-9.236,15.426-18.521,30.822-27.666,46.302c-0.92,1.559-1.714,3.759-1.367,5.407
 c2.677,12.698,5.788,25.306,8.403,38.016c0.459,2.23-0.192,5.144-1.345,7.163c-2.932,5.138-6.438,9.948-10.477,16.041
 c16.966,12.396,33.576,24.6,50.323,36.61c1.069,0.767,3.474,0.583,4.803-0.075c7.905-3.912,15.675-8.096,23.492-12.186
 c12.945-6.773,25.893-13.544,38.832-20.312c-0.51-3.013-1.264-5.614-1.321-8.23c-0.09-4.039-2.078-4.854-5.711-4.753
 c-8.326,0.231-16.664,0.073-24.997,0.073c-6.755,0-13.511,0-21.22,0c1.239-1.565,1.725-2.357,2.375-2.978
 c24.954-23.8,49.887-47.621,74.97-71.284c1.585-1.495,4.331-2.395,6.566-2.454c9.826-0.261,19.665-0.008,29.495-0.179
 c2.749-0.048,5.643-0.491,8.202-1.462c42.308-16.051,84.498-32.415,126.928-48.134c6.283-2.328,7.825-5.511,8.036-11.447
 c0.371-10.48,1.478-20.935,2.256-31.401c0.197-2.654,0.906-4.529,3.972-5.421c28.269-8.229,56.509-16.56,84.691-25.079
 c2.456-0.742,5.064-2.595,6.549-4.681c13.707-19.271,27.224-38.678,40.646-58.148c1.088-1.578,1.779-4.05,1.447-5.889
 c-3.131-17.359-6.355-34.706-9.89-51.987c-3.36-16.432-3.513-16.365,9.784-26.776c4.75-3.719,9.355-7.62,14.828-12.094
 c-19.724-3.718-38.169-7.272-56.663-10.557c-1.843-0.327-4.22,0.592-5.942,1.616c-18.455,10.984-36.851,22.069-55.199,33.231
 c-2.703,1.645-4.71,1.894-7.509-0.145c-9.55-6.954-19.31-13.627-29.098-20.247c-1.701-1.151-3.89-2.026-5.919-2.184
 c-44.502-3.464-89.014-6.771-133.258-12.938c-3.511-0.49-4.665-1.627-5.216-5.018C184.862,55.08,182.774,45.012,180.778,34.489z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks again for sharing your code. I have given it a try and this is what  I have on this link : https://jsfiddle.net/5sv6nzh3/1/
I am almost there if you can help me to edit it on the jsfiddle.net I will be more than happy. I think I am missing out something.

Comment: You are using a _very_ small `viewBox`for the SVG: `viewBox="-0.0153376 -0.0153376 1.25768 1.13823"`. In order to see the "marker" you need to change the width and the height of the `<use>` to .1 : `<use id="theUse" xlink:href="#marker" width=".1" height=".1"  />` The other problem is that the chosen path is slanted and the pin seams to fall outside the path.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have  managed to solve my problem